# Bug in Asus Zenfone max pro m2

Tags: settings, 9.0-pie, bugs

I've found a serious privacy bug in system app of stock android 9.0 of Asus Zenfone Max pro m2. The problem is I am confused about where to file this bug? Should I go for [Report bugs: Android](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs) or should I use ZenUI forums?

Answer (score 2):

Since [it is stock Android](https://m.gsmarena.com/asus_zenfone_max_pro_m2-review-1873p3.php), it would be appropriate  posting as directed in the link you included in the question. Make sure it's not already reported. If it is, you can either *star* (you would get mail updates) or  add if your observations add more information

In addition, report on Asus official forums too, since you say it is a *serious* bug.

Comment: Thank you. I'll add it to the official ZenUI forums too.